# Postgresql export ddl with comments

Tags: sql, postgresql, export, comments

I have a problem with exporting ddl with comments. I can export the functions, schema's etc, however I can't export the description together with the ddl. Any idea how to do this? I can see the description under the ddl when I open the ddl. But it won't export the way I can see it?

Comment: Are you using pgAdmin III?

Comment: No, why do I need to use the pgAdmin III?

Comment: I see what you are trying to tell me but I don't want to do it by hand, for every single function. I want to be able to export a single function with comments. With the use of a script, so that I can use it multiple times.